# html - send custom fonts to the user

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have specific fonts I want to use in my website, but the client doesn't necessarily have them too.
All I want to do is to send the client my own fonts in order to display them in his browser.
Is it possible?

EDIT:

I want to use the fonts dynamically with javascript - means to change them as a result of the user behavior.
so I can't just call a font in a css class, I need to call a src font in my run time code.

the answers I got don't do it, I think...
can you just give me a line of code?

thanks

Comment: Do you have a license to distribute these fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out [CSS Fonts Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-webfonts/).

Answer (score 0):

Google has a quite nice API for this:

http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/webfonts/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe @font-face is what you are looking for